# Create a pie chart in excel for pass and fail values

Tags: excel, excel-charts, vba

I have done some manual testing for the website where I have 3 different test results on Desktop, Tablet and Mobile for a single test case. Now I want to represent all of my test results into a Pie Chart where it will show the total number of Pass, Fail and Partial test case results. [Attached image is the example how I am representing this in the Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lXP8.png).

Comment: So far no question has been asked, and there's no connection to programming.  Have you finished?

Comment: Yes, this is it! I need some help with excel. I want to represent the total %age of Pass results and %age of fail results in chart form. Please let me know if you require further information.

Comment: I have tried inserting it with the normal Pie chart function and also assigned the colour value to its cells too. But the graph is coming out blank.

Comment: show your code and some sample data and you're more likely to get help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code to get you started.  It will produce the pie chart shown here as long as you put the data in `A1:F2`.  Notice that two of the sections are colored: for windows pass (solid red) and windows fail (gradient red).  You could do the same to the other categories, of course, by extending what I've started for you here.

[image]

```
Sub pie()
Dim r As Range, chObj As ChartObject, pt1 As Point, pt2 As Point
Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:F2")
Set chObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=100, Width:=375, Top:=75, Height:=225)
    With chObj
        .Chart.SetSourceData Source:=r
        .Chart.ChartType = xlPie
        Set pt1 = .Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(1)
        Set pt2 = .Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(2)
    End With
  With pt1.Format.Fill
      .Visible = msoTrue
      .ForeColor.RGB = vbRed 'RGB(255, 0, 0)
      .Transparency = 0
      .Solid
    End With
  With pt2.Format.Fill
      .Visible = msoTrue
      .ForeColor.RGB = vbRed 'RGB(255, 0, 0)
      .TwoColorGradient msoGradientDiagonalUp, 1
      .Transparency = 0
    End With
    chObj.Chart.HasLegend = True
    chObj.Chart.Legend.Height = 100
End Sub
```